# How to associate the results from function to the polygons in your SVG map?

Tags: laravel, svg

I have svg map, it has polygons and it has unique id name based on the purok name such as purok 1, purok 2, purok 3 as the region of hte map, now i have a function from the controller that returns the number of disease from each purok based on the disease the user has selected from the options in the disease dropdown, now I want to associate the result from the countDisease function to my svg map, how would I aligned the polygons from svg map with their id="purok 1" to the number of infected respondents by each purok?

I use laravel to count the selected disease option from the dropdown of each puroks in the map.

```
 $diseaseCounts = HouseholdHead::whereHas('respondents.diseases', function ($query) use ($selectedDiseaseId) {
    $query->where('disease_id', $selectedDiseaseId);
})->with('puroks')->groupBy('purok_id')->selectRaw('count(*) as count, purok_id')->get();
```

I want to associate the color intensity base on the number of result as well in my views.

Comment: Is the SVG part of the view/blade file? If so, you can set the fill attribute on each polygon based on the number. You can also give each polygon a class name based on the number and then have CSS selectors matching with the right fill color.